# `aws ssm start-session` not working from inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, aws-cli, ssm

i have a docker container based off https://github.com/bopen/docker-ubuntu-pyenv/blob/master/Dockerfile
...where i'm installing the aws-cli and would like to use aws ssm to access a remote instance.

i've tried starting the container with `docker-compose` AND with `docker up` -- in both cases i've mounted my `AWS_PROFILE`, and can access all other aws-cli commands (i tested with `ec2 describe` and even did an `aws ssm send-command` to the instance!)

BUT when i do `aws ssm start-session --target $instance_id` from the container, i get nothing. i'm able to run aws ssm start-session from my local shell to this instance so i know that ssm is configured properly.

running it with the `--debug` flag gives me the exact same output from when i run it locally, minus the `Starting session with SessionId:` part obviously.

is this a aws-cli issue? or some weird container stdout thing? help pls!

[cross posted here https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4465]

Answer (score 2):

okayyy so the 'fix' for this was that the Session Manager Plugin on the container was not installed properly. 
i guess the plugin isn't actually 'optional' as this says https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html, but is required to start a session with SSM.
i had the wrong plugin installed and `session-manager-plugin` was returning an error. getting the right one in the container fixed everything!